# Decompress gz file using R

Tags: r, gzip

I have used `?unzip` in the past to get at contents of a zipped file using R.  This time around, I am having a hard time extracting the files from a .gz file which can be found [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/chadwick/files/chadwick-0.5/0.5.3/chadwick-0.5.3.tar.gz/download).

I have tried `?gzfile` and `?gzcon` but have not been able to get it to work.  Any help you can provide will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

If you really want to uncompress the file, just use the `untar` function which does support *gzip*.
E.g.:

```
untar('chadwick-0.5.3.tar.gz')
```

Answer (score 80):

Here is a worked example that may help illustrate what `gzfile()` and `gzcon()` are for

```
foo <- data.frame(a=LETTERS[1:3], b=rnorm(3))
foo
#  a        b
#1 A 0.586882
#2 B 0.218608
#3 C 1.290776
write.table(foo, file="/tmp/foo.csv")
system("gzip /tmp/foo.csv")             # being very explicit
```

Now that the file is written, instead of implicit use of `file()`, use `gzfile()`:

```
read.table(gzfile("/tmp/foo.csv.gz"))   
#  a        b
#1 A 0.586882
#2 B 0.218608
#3 C 1.290776
```

The file you point is a compressed tar archive, and as far as I know, R itself has no interface to tar archives. These are commonly used to distribute source code--as for example for R packages and R sources.

Comment: is it possible to do this with `fread{data.table}` ? I have tried without success so far

Comment: That is obvious yet not useful as data.table cannot consume that stream.

Comment: That's useful.  Its standard heuristic tries reading in three different locations which requires forward/backward positioning you cannot do on a stream.   I looked for freak support once and think I saw 'nope'  but maybe that has changed.

Comment: Current version of `data.table` in fact supports `csv.gz` natively (no need for `zcat`)

Comment: `gzfile` also worked for me on `txt.gz` where `untar` failed (I didn't finagle with `untar` too much)

Comment: This should work now (+9 years after)library(data.table)
library(R.utils)

d <- fread("file.gz",stringsAsFactors = F)

Answer (score 68):

To un-gz a file in R you can do

```
library(R.utils)
gunzip("file.gz", remove=FALSE)
```

or

```
gunzip("file.gz")
```

But then you get the default (remove=TRUE) behavior in which the input file is removed after that the output file is fully created and closed.

Comment: Thats what i was looking for. Be aware: `NOTE: The default (remove=TRUE) behavior is that the input file is removed after that the output file is fully created and closed.` - see `?gunzip`

Comment: `gunzip()` is now deprecated

Comment: @iskandarblue where do you see that? Can't find anywhere saying that gunzip is deprecated.

Answer (score 29):

http://blog.revolutionanalytics.com/2009/12/r-tip-save-time-and-space-by-compressing-data-files.html

R added transparent decompression for certain kinds of compressed files in the latest version (2.10).  If you have your files compressed with bzip2, xvz, or gzip they can be read into R as if they are plain text files. You should have the proper filename extensions.

The command...

```
myData <- read.table('myFile.gz')
```

#gzip compressed files have a "gz" extension

Will work just as if 'myFile.gz' were the raw text file.

Comment: It does work unless you specify colClasses argument.
If you add

    myData <- read.table('myFile.gz', colClasses=c("character", "integer")) 

then you will get an error (as of R 3.2.0). Crap.

Answer (score 4):

If it's a comma/tab-separated file, you can use **data.table**'s `fread()`. It can handle zipped (.zip, .gz) files:

```r
fread('myFile.csv.gz')
```

Answer (score 3):

```
library(vroom)
columns3 = c('A', 'B',...) ## define column names
Data1<- vroom(".../XXX.tsv",col_names = columns3)
```

works fine with `tsv.gz`