# How to read gzipped files from HDFS in R?

Tags: r, gzip, hdfs

Uinsg rhdfs it's possible to read files from HDFS in R. However, my files on HDFS are gzip-compressed. How do I read the plain text content of gzipped files on HDFS into R?

Things I've tried so far:

`gzcon(hdfs.file(path))` -> `Error in gzcon(...) : 'con' is not a connection`

`memDecompress(hdfs.read(hdfs.file(path)), type="g")` -> `Error in memDecompress(..., type = "g") :  internal error -3 in memDecompress(2)`

Also tried `memDecompress` with `type="u"`.

Comment: Does [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5764499/decompress-gz-file-using-r) help?

Comment: Unfortunately not, because my files aren't .tar.gz files, just .gz. Using `untar` on a plain .gz file gives /bin/gtar: This does not look like a tar archive
/bin/gtar: Skipping to next header
/bin/gtar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors

Comment: How about the second answer from Dirk in the same post I've linked?

Comment: That doesn't work either---`gzfile` takes a path or url or clipboard or `stdin`. None of these options reasonably allows interfacing with HDFS.