# Extracting gzip files over the network

Tags: windows, r, unzip, gunzip

I am using R.2.15.2 on Windows 7 and I cannot unzip a `.gz` file stored on the network.
I am also using `gnuwin32` (if it helps)

The file is seen, so the location is ok

```
system("ls")
file1.bla.gz
file2.bla.gz
file3.bla.gz
...

R) unzip("./file1.bla.gz")
Message d'avis :
In unzip("./file1.bla.gz") :
erreur 1 lors de l'extraction d'un fichier zip

R) untar("./file1.bla.gz")
/usr/bin/tar: This does not look like a tar archive
/usr/bin/tar: Skipping to next header
```

Using the function `unzip` is nor working, it looks like it is only dealing with `.zip` files. Not sure if the problem lies in the network or if I call It wrongly...

How can I extract this file ?

**EDIT**: The following worked

```
system(" \"C:\\Program Files\\7-Zip\\7z.exe\" e -y file1.bla.gz")
```

And `gunzip` from `R.utils` is even better thanks to @Paul Hiemstra

Comment: Define "not working". What are read/write options of that particular file/folder?

Comment: Have you tried using `gzfile`?

Comment: @RomanLuštrik: not working == I can not find a way to decompress the file within R
James: I just tried, gzfile("the gz file name") with no success

Comment: No success?! How can we help with no error messages, and no code? Please post these

Comment: I would avoid literally calling `7zip`, this makes the code much less portable. See my updated answer for opening gzip compressed files using `gzfile`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `gzfile` to access the content of a `gzip` compressed file, for example:

```
read.table(gzfile("/tmp/foo.csv.gz"))
```

where `foo.csv.gz` is a gzip compressed csv file. I got this form @DirkEddelbuettel's answer in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5764499/decompress-gz-file-using-r).

If your goal is to extract the file, you can use the `gunzip` function from the `R.utils` package. See [this](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2010-September/252896.html) R-help post.

Comment: Well I thought it worked, but not, so this is for `.tar` archives not `.gz`

Comment: `tar` also supports extracting `gzip` archives as they are often used in tandem. `tar` to create a single file which contains all the files, and `gzip` to add compression.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5764499/decompress-gz-file-using-r says it should work.

Comment: I don't think so, the link you are refering to call for `untar` if `tar.gz` which is not my case. I edited to show you the failure message

Comment: You can use `gzfile` to access a gzip compressed file, see my updated answer.

Comment: Paul, I would do this if the goal was to load the data into `R`, but the only thing I want is to unzip the file plain and simple... Anyway since version 2.10 I think, you can read a `csv.gz` file directly anyway with `read.table` see http://blog.revolutionanalytics.com/2009/12/r-tip-save-time-and-space-by-compressing-data-files.html

Comment: You can use `gunzip` from the `R.utils` package.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28382/discussion-between-paul-hiemstra-and-statquant)