# uncompress a big .gz file

Tags: r, compression, kaggle

I need to uncompress a `transactions.gz` file downloaded from Kaggle; approximately (2.86 GB), 350 million rows, 11 columns.

I tried on RStudio, windows Vista, 32 bits, RAM: 3 GB:

```
transactions <- read.table(gzfile("E:/2014/Proyectos/Kaggle/transactions.gz"))
write.table(transactions, file="E:/2014/Proyectos/Kaggle/transactions.csv")
```

But i receive this error message on the console

```
> transactions <- read.table(gzfile("E:/2014/Proyectos/Kaggle/transactions.gz"))
Error: cannot allocate vector of size 64.0 Mb
> write.table(transactions, file="E:/2014/Proyectos/Kaggle/transactions.csv")
Error: cannot allocate vector of size 64.0 Mb
```

I checked this case, but it didn't work for me: [Decompress gz file using R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5764499/decompress-gz-file-using-r)

I would appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: What platform are you on?  If linux-based you can interface with the unix/shell terminal and process it there before you bring it into R.

Comment: Thanks, rigth now I have my .csv file

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This file decompresses to a 22GB .csv file. You can't process it all at once in R on your 6GB machine because R needs to read everything into memory. It would be best to process it in an RDBMS like postgresql. If you are intent on using R you could process it in chunks, reading a manageable number of rows at a time: read a chunk, process it, and then overwrite with the next chunk. For this `data.table::fread` would be better than the standard `read.table`.

Oh, and don't decompress in R, just run `gunzip` from the command line and then process the csv. If you're on Windows you can use winzip or 7zip.

Comment: I don't like applications that delete their input files, and thus don't use `gunzip` directly.  Rather, I'll use `gzip -c -d`.

Comment: OK, but this prints to stdout and requires redirection, right? `gzip -c -d file.csv.gz > file.csv`, or `zcat file.csv.gz > file.csv`. Probably `gunzip -k file.csv.gz` is simplest.

Comment: Sure, good luck in the competition. I am in Shoppers as well.

Comment: Nice, I am going to explore purchase behavior to predict.

Comment: I guess you are using amazon dataset, aha