# R download.File error cannot open URl

Tags: r

```
temp <- tempfile()
download.file("file://connect/me/test.gz",temp)
```

The url exists because I can put it in my browser but when I run that code I get the error:

```
  Error in download.file("file://connect/me/test.gz",  : 
    cannot open URL "file://connect/me/test.gz", reason 'No such file or directory'
```

any ideas how i can download the file and unzip it?

#### UPDATE

I found some info on fil:// here  https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/connections.html:

"A note on file:// URLs. The most general form (from RFC1738) is file://host/path/to/file, but R only accepts the form with an empty host field referring to the local machine."

"In this form the path is relative to the root of the filesystem, not a Windows concept. The standard form on Windows is file:///d:/R/repos: for compatibility with earlier versions of R and Unix versions, any other form is parsed as R as file:// plus path_to_file. Also, backslashes are accepted within the path even though RFC1738 does not allow them."

What does that mean?

ty

Comment: Maybe add additional `/`? Something like `download.file("file://connect//me//test.gz",temp)`

Comment: @David - I tried that and get the same error. Do you think it is because the address begins with "file" and not "www"

Comment: @David do you know what the update means?

Comment: It seem to mean that you need to remove the host from the URL

Comment: ha yea so what does that mean the url should look like? i think that why the person below said use /// 3 slashes for the empty host but that doesnt seem to work

Comment: The address doesn't begin with `file`, `file` is the scheme, replacing `http` (or a lot of other options).  R only will let you use the file scheme for local files.  That's what the update is saying.  You need to use the full windows path, starting with the letter.

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out. I had to map a drive "B" to the folder and then

```
temp <- tempfile()
download.file("file:///B:/me/test.gz",temp,method="internal")
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need three slashes after file: and one slash for the rest. I tried this on windows 7 and it works fine.

```
    temp <- tempfile()
    download.file("file:///C:/Users/Philip/Desktop/Coursera/data/cameras.csv",temp)
```

Comment: My take, @user3022875: when you see a non-file URL, you see something like `http://some.host.com/path/to/filename`. R does not support the `file:` URI with a remote host, so the host field needs to be blank. So what is a technically legal URI of `file://remote.host.com/path/to/file` needs to have the remote hostname (but not the surrounding slashes) removed, leaving `file:///path/to/file`. Note the three slashes.