# Iteratively skip the last rows in CSV files when using read_csv

Tags: r, purrr, readr

I have a number of CSV files exported from our database, say `site1_observations.csv`, `site2_observations.csv`, `site3_observations.csv` etc. Each CSV looks like below (site1 for example):

| Column A | Column B | Column C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| # Team: all teams |  |  |
| # Observation type: xyz |  |  |
| Site ID | Reason | Quantity |
| a | xyz | 1 |
| b | abc | 2 |
| Total quantity | 3 |  |

We need to skip the top 2 rows and the last 1 row from each CSV before combining them as a whole master dataset for further analysis. I know I can use the `skip =` argument to skip the first few lines of CSV, but `read_csv()` doesn't seem to have simple argument to skip the last lines and I have been using `n_max =` as a workaround. The data import has been done in manual way. I want to shift the manual process to programmatic manner using `purrr::map()`, but just couldn't work out how to efficiently skip the last few lines here.

```
library(tidyverse)

observations_skip_head <- 2

# Approach 1: manual ----
site1_rawdata <- read_csv("/data/site1_observations.csv", 
                          skip = observations_skip_head, 
                          n_max = nrow(read_csv("/data/site1_observations.csv", 
                                                skip = observations_skip_head))-1)

# site2_rawdata
# site3_rawdata
# [etc]

# all_sites_rawdata <- bind_rows(site1_rawdata, site2_rawdata, site3_rawdata, [etc])
```

I have tried to use `purrr::map()` and I believe I am almost there, except the `n_max =` part which I am not sure how/what to do this in `map()` (or any other effective way to get rid of the last line in each CSV). How to do this with purrr?

```
observations_csv_paths_chr <- paste0("data/site", 1:3,"_observations.csv")

# Approach 2: programmatically import csv files with purrr ----

all_sites_rawdata <- observations_csv_paths_chr %>% 
  
  map(~ read_csv(., skip = observations_skip_head, 
                 n_max = nrow(read_csv("/data/site1_observations.csv", 
                                       skip = observations_skip_head))-1)) %>% 
  set_names(observations_csv_paths_chr)
```

I know [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36558437/) uses a custom function and `fread`. But for my education I want to understand how to achieve this goal using the `purrr` approach (if it's doable).

Comment: Why not filter out the last row? `df %>% filter(\`Column A\` != "Total quantity")`.  You could also use `nrow` to compute the number of rows and `head` to take all but the last one.

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this?

```
library(tidyverse)

csv_files <- paste0("data/site", 1:3, "_observations.csv")

csv_files |>
  map(
    ~ .x |> 
      read_lines() |> 
      tail(-3) |>   # skip first 3
      head(-2) |>   # ..and last 2
      paste(collapse = '\n') |>
      read_csv()
  )
```

Comment: Hi Peter, it seems working - until it gives error at `read_csv()`. It says `colname1, colname2 (etc) does not exist in current working directory`. I thought the subdirectory had been included in the `csv_files` i.e. "data/" but it seems somehow it's not looking into the subdirectory in this very last step. Am I missing something here?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to do `paste(collapse='\n')`. I just edited my answer - should work now.

Answer (score 0):

```
manual_csv<-function(x) { 
  txt<-readLines(x)
  txt<-txt[-c(2,3,length(txt))] # insert the row you want to delete
  result<-read.csv(text=paste0(txt, collapse="\n"))
}
test<-manual_csv('D:/jaechang/pool/final.csv')
```