# Import raw bytes as raw bytes in R

Tags: r, postgresql, encoding

I have imported a string into R from a database. The db column type is `BYTEA` (Postgres). In order for me to use it as intended, it should be of type `raw`. Instead, it is of type `character`. I want to convert it to raw in the following sense:

The string representation is

```
\x1f8b080000000000
```

If I use `charToRaw`, it is converted to the array

```
5c 78 31 66 38 62 30 38
```

Instead I need it to be the array

```
1f 8b 08 00 00 00 00 00
```

How do I acheive this.

**Edit #1** Reply to Chris

```
library(RPostgreSQL)
conn <- dbConnect(dbDriver("PostgreSQL"), dbname = "somename",
                  host = "1.2.3.4", port = 5432,
                  user = "someuser", password = pw)
some_value <- dbGetQuery(conn, "select value from schema.key_value where key like '%somekey%' limit 1")

some_value$value
# [1] "\\x1f8b080000000000000
```

Comment: can you share the code you used to import from the database?

Comment: maybe cast to string in Postgres and then `charToRaw` once back in R? A better way would be to cast directly to raw in Postgres, not sure if that is possible though

Comment: Tried `select convert_to(value::text, 'utf-8') as value from schema.key_value ...`  then `charToRaw()` without success. Valiant effort though.

Answer (score 4):

This works for converting a single character string of the type you've described to a vector of raws.

```
## The string I think you're talking about
dat <- "\\x1f8b080000000000"
cat(dat, "\n")
## \x1f8b080000000000

## A function to convert one string to an array of raw
f <- function(x)  {
    ## Break into two-character segments
    x <- strsplit(x, "(?<=.{2})", perl=TRUE)[[1]]
    ## Remove the first element, "\\x"
    x <- x[-1]
    ## Complete the conversion
    as.raw(as.hexmode(x))
}

## Check that it works
f(dat)
##  [1] 1f 8b 08 00 00 00 00 00
```

Comment: I'm a little shocked that I can't do this in a native way. Seems really inefficient. I'm leaning toward handling this in python or bash.

Comment: @artdv Shocked that you can't more simply convert strings like `"\\x1f...."` to raw vectors? Or shocked that you can't get data directly from a database into a raw vector? In any case, yeah, I'd definitely suggest using something you like and are more comfortable with, if you've got it at the ready.

Comment: The latter more than the former. If I want to store binary versions of R objects in a database, what is the desired approach?

Comment: @artdv -- I haven't a clue what's the best approach, esp. since I don't know your use case. Perhaps as paths to `"*.rds"` files (containing serialized R objects, as written to disk by `saveRDS()` (and readable by `readRDS()`))?

Comment: `1f 8b` suggests this is a gzipped byte array. How do you decompress the result?

Comment: @BrianD Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5764499/decompress-gz-file-using-r

Comment: not as much as this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50996686/how-to-decode-postgresql-bytea-column-hex-to-int16-uint16-in-r  ;)