# R package development best practices: using system() command?

Tags: r

I'm developing a new R package to release to CRAN and would like to invoke the `system()` command directly within its source code.  For example, I would like to use the `gzip` utility directly within my R package:

```
write.csv(mydat, "mydat.csv")
system("gzip mydat.csv", wait=FALSE)
```

Even more importantly, I would like to leverage other existing command-line utilities directly within my R package.  And by command-line utilities, I mean actual large command-line software programs that are *not trivial* to rewrite in R.

So my question is: **What are some best practices for specifying the usage of external (not R) command-line libraries during the development of an R package?**

For example, the `Imports` and `Depends` fields in an R package `DESCRIPTION` file are only good for specifying the usage of *existing R libraries* within your R package.  It would be a nuisance for users to have to manually install some existing *non-R* command-line library by using a package manager (e.g., brew), and this would go against best practices of self-contained work within an R Studio IDE.  Besides, there is no guarantee that such a roundabout approach would work in a reproducible fashion, due to the difficulty of properly matching full paths to the command-line executable, coordinating with the R Studio IDE, etc.

Likewise, using tools such as https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ssh.utils/index.html will only serve basic command-line needs within the R environment, and hence does not apply to the needs of using large command-line software programs.

**Note:** The R package that I'm developing is not for personal use.  It is intended for public release to CRAN and, hence, should comply with their checks.  However, I could not find any specification from CRAN regarding the use of the `system()` command, particularly in the context of leveraging actual large command-line software programs that are not trivial to rewrite in R.

Comment: In the `DESCRIPTION` file of your package, you can specify the `SystemRequirements` section with the needed dependencies. You should then write a configure script that tests whether the system has them. However, I don't think it's a good practice to call `system`. If you rely on an external library, a cleaner way should be to wrap it so it can be called directly from R.

Comment: Spot on. And what we do in `x13binary` ensuring the presence of the tool we require (and provide).

Comment: @nicola When you say: "However, I don't think it's a good practice to call system. If you rely on an external library, a cleaner way should be to wrap it so it can be called directly from R." ... how do you wrap code from an existing library (assuming it's not an R library) without calling `system()`?

Comment: You write C (or C++) code using R/C interfaces like `.Call` or `.External` or the `Rcpp` package. See this link http://adv-r.had.co.nz/C-interface.html to get started on how to call C from R. See for instance the `rgeos`, `rgdal` or other packages that do exactly this: wrap an external library so it can be called from R.

Comment: @nicola:  Good comment, but no need to refer to external documentation as Rcpp has plenty of that itself, and no need to look at difficult/obscure packages like `rgeos` or `gdal` which do not use Rcpp.  Plenty of recent, simple, well-written packages using Rcpp from the likes of Jeroen, Hadley, Oliver, Bob Rudis, ...

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel You are absolutely right. I' more used with the "bare" C interface and those packages were the first that came into my mind. I guess hundreds of libraries are wrapped in R using `Rcpp`, so OP will for sure be able to accomplish their goal using just `Rcpp` tools and doc (especially if they got some kind of experience in C++). However, I'm under the impression that OP is hoping for a copy/paste kind of solution that didn't require basically any work. I guess they didn't go over your answer with the needed care.

Answer (score 0):

> I would like to use the gzip utility directly within my R package

That is a code smell.  *Your* package then needs to determine by means of `configure` (or similar) if such programs exist. So why bother?  In this example, and on my box:

```
edd@don:~$ grep  GZIP /etc/R/Renviron
R_GZIPCMD=${R_GZIPCMD-'/bin/gzip -n'}
edd@don:~$
```

You have access to it via most file-saving commands such as `saveRDS()`, the `gzcon()` and `gzfile()` functions and so on. See [this older answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5764537/143305) of mine.

For truly external programs you can rely on `system()`. See Christoph's [seasonal](https://cloud.r-project.org/web/packages/seasonal/index.html) package relying on our underlying [x13binary](https://cloud.r-project.org/web/packages/x13binary/index.html) binary package.

Comment: The `x13binary` package is an R package.  I'm explicitly referring to command-line software packages (not necessarily written in R) that are NOT available in the R ecosystem (e.g., R Studio IDE).

Comment: Please pay a bit more attention to detail.  The [x13binary](https://cloud.r-project.org/web/packages/x13binary/index.html) _package_ supplies (via custom installer code) a _binary_ irrespective of operating system and platform to be accessed from R via `system()` --- exactly what you ask for here -- but doing it _carefully_ and _portably_ via R wrapper code.  All of this may well be a little harder than you currently think it is.