# Concurrent requests gziped response

Tags: r, rcurl, httr

Is there any package that can send concurrent requests and handle gzipped response?

The `httr` package from what I see it cannot handle asynchronous requests while from `RCurl::getURIAsynchronous` returns only gzipped content and I don't really know how to unzip it.

Is there any way to unzip it on-the-fly?

Comment: It's Windows 10

Comment: Relevant post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5764499/decompress-gz-file-using-r

Comment: But it would require me to save it, right? I can't do it.