# how to extract text in R

Tags: r

when i pass this

```
 String encoded = Base64.encodeBytes(String.valueOf("who are you").getBytes(),Base64.GZIP);
```

this gzip data how can i decompress in R (sending this in R via API)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Decompress gz file using R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5764499/decompress-gz-file-using-r)

Comment: There are multiple ways of executing java code in R: https://www.r-bloggers.com/a-primer-in-using-java-from-r-part-1/